# why compiler selected copy constructor in place assignment operator in this example?

Tags: c++

I am confused by what seemingly seems to be a simple matter related to copy constructor at step# 2 below and please give example when  foo& operator=(foo &&other) is used.

```
 foo foo1;
 foo foo2=foo1; // why it uses foo(const foo &other); constructor instead of foo& operator=(const foo &other) 
 foo2 = foo1; // ok, it uses foo& operator=(const foo &other) 

 A obj6(move(obj5)); // ok it uses foo(foo &&other)
```

Comment: Because it's [initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), not assignment.

Comment: "please give example when `foo& operator=(foo &&other)` is used." For example, `foo2 = foo{};` But you seem to be asking two separate questions.

Comment: Or `foo2 = move(foo1);`.

Comment: Yes, the `=` in an initialization might look like an assignment operator but it is not.

Comment: Thanks songyunyao .

Comment: The `=` in `foo foo2=foo1;` is just a superficial syntactic element - a part of initialization syntax - that has absolutely no relaton to assignment operator. The matter of using assignment operator in this context does not even arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> foo foo2=foo1; // why it uses foo(const foo &other); constructor instead of foo& operator=(const foo &other)
> ```

Because that is syntax for copy-initialization. Copy initialization uses the copy (or move) constructor, not copy (or move) assignment operator.